# Implementing next / before month / year method in PrimeVue Calendar

Tags: vue.js, calendar, primevue

I want to have a custom button that shows next/before month/year in PrimeVue. It has a calendar component but could not find the available method to implement the function.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I could replace the element with css and dom selector but this one just changes to next/previous month. I want to have button to change next/previous year as well. And they do not provide both functions at the same time.